# Typescript (Angular) - JSON model Deserialisation

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http, deserialization

I would like to add and populate additional fields (which are not sent by backend service) in my http model. **Catch is that I am not able to populate (map) those fields in the place where http response is being received** since I am using internal framework.

Is there a possibility in Typescript (Angular) to somehow override JSON Deserialisation flow/Instance creation and populate mentioned fields. For example:

```
interface ElectricDevice {
    
    energy_meter_start: number; // received from backend service
    energy_meter_stop: number; // received from backend service

    energy_spent: number; // not received by backend service, but needs to be populated as energy_meter_stop - energy_meter_start

    // ...

    /* I would like to somehow populate energy_spent as energy_meter_stop-energy_meter_end on instance creation (deserialisation) */

}
```

Comment: Could you add to your question how you do the http call? Or at least, the part when you subscribe to the service which make the http call. Thxs!

Answer (score 0):

You need a [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor), in which you can manipulate data.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomJsonInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private jsonParser: JsonParser) {}

  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (httpRequest.responseType === 'json') {
      // If the expected response type is JSON then handle it here.
      return this.handleJsonResponse(httpRequest, next);
    } else {
      return next.handle(httpRequest);
    }
  }
```

Read more about it in the tutorials: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

I have asked you for the especific names of your services.

But, in the meantime, I give you a 'general' answer to your question.
You just need to do this:

```
this.yourService.yourGetElectriceDevices
.pipe(
   map (_resp: ElectricDevice  => _resp.energy_spent = _resp.energy_meter_stop - _resp.energy_meter_start
)
.subscribe( resp => { //your treatment to the response });
```

This above, only works for a rapid test.
If you want to do somethig more 'elaborated', you could transform your interface into a class, and add your calculated attribute, something like this:

```
export interface ElectricDevice {
    
    energy_meter_start: number; // received from backend service
    energy_meter_stop: number; // received from backend service
  
}

export Class ElectricDeviceClass {

energy_meter_start: number;
energy_meter_stop: number;

energy_spent: number; 


constructor (data: ElectricDevice)  {
   this.energy_meter_start = data.energy_meter_start;
   this.energy_meter_stop= data.energy_meter_stop;

   this.energy_spent = this.energy_meter_stop - this.energy_meter_start;
}
```

And for using it, just:

```
import { ElectricDeviceClass, ElectricDevice } from './../model/...' // There where you have yours interfaces and model classes

this.yourService.yourGetElectriceDevices
.pipe(
   map (_resp: ElectricDevice  => new ElectricDeviceClass(_resp)
)
.subscribe( resp => { //your treatment to the response });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I've mentioned, I am using specific internal framework for handling http layer so I am not able to perform suggested transformation. I can able to do something meaningful only on model level.